# Close Votes Outside the Queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

Why do Close Votes not count when they are outside of the review queue? I close vote quite a few questions per day as I see them (I no longer visit the review sector because it simply angers me, and when it doesn't, I get bored, make a mistake and I'm banned (no big deal, I just don't go there anymore because it presents too many off topic questions/edits I don't care about)), and I was wondering if there is a reason why outside queue CV's don't count towards the review badge?

I'm not too concerned about the badge, cleaning the JavaScript tag is just what I do.

Comment: Closing things while seeing them is not the same feeling as reviewing in a queue.

Comment: It's the exact same thing, it's just not in list form. Feels exactly the same to me, even better at that. It's less of a mindless close vote spree.

Comment: Rewarding "mindless close vote spree"s is what the badge is for.

Comment: Sorry, if you're being serious, that's not a good reason in my personal opinion. Like minded tasks should be rewarded the same. Besides, outside the queue takes much longer. (I'm not sure if there is an outside queue CV limit? That might be why)

Comment: Fine, that's a separate badge. It has nothing to do with reviewing.

Comment: False, you're reviewing a question. 100% related

Comment: That's like saying upvoting new user's questions should count toward the first post review queue. No.

Comment: That analogy makes no sense (to me at least), and you can argue an analogy to anything. Of course making an upvote count towards first post makes no sense. but close votes are 95% similar aside from casting vs. reviewing others votes

Comment: Review is going thru a list. I don't see how not going thru a list can count as going thru a list.

Comment: List is convention, it's not a set in stone rule. What's so wrong with deviating from a simple standard?

Comment: You can't redefine the english language for the sake of it. Fine, request a new badge. But you can't redefine what a review queue is.

Comment: I believe redefining a language has existed since the birth of spoken/written language. They are always being redefined. British English => American English is a basic example. But yeah, I'm not hard headed here, I'd just like to see either a close vote badge or some integration to review counting. Or not, not a huge deal.

Comment: Redefining a language for a reason is fine. But you have not presented one great enough for everyone to start calling everything a review queue.

Comment: @bjb568 do me a favor and don't speak for everybody, let everybody decide for themselves ;)

Comment: I mean "everyone" as in "there are way too many people with opinions and things to do to consider redefining something that doesn't need to be redefined"

Comment: Voting to close on the question itself is **not the same as reviewing**. In the review queue you can vote to leave the post open, for example. Enough such votes kicks the post out of the queue. You are *reviewing close votes*, and that is not the same thing as closing a post directly.

Comment: I suggest modifying the [Moderator Badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) description(s) for these to read *"Completed at least nnn **Review Queue** task. This badge is awarded once per **Review Queue** type."*. That would seem to me to remove the ambiguity that led me to this question to begin with.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The point of the badge is to show you the queue exists (for the "first review action" ones) and to encourage you to develop a habit of checking the queue regularly and working in the queue. Case in point: voting to Leave Open is an action that counts towards the badge in the queue. Should reading a post with one close vote but not clicking close (outside the queue) count towards the badge?

If you get review banned a lot, you might want to read some of the many questions here and on meta.se about reviewing, to ensure you understand the heuristics reviewers are expected to follow. Or, you might decide that you don't like reviewing at all and stop doing it. That's cool, but that means you won't be getting the badge. It's for reviewing, not for closing.

Comment: Understandable completely

Comment: Case in point: voting to Reopen at a forum level is an action that requires review of the question in its current state, possibly modified through edits. I understand the *why* of the current system but I think the reasoning is thin. Exercising a VTC in one of the forums you frequent seems to add credibility to the VTC through implied expertise.

Comment: @Jeeped your comment doesn't make sense to me. In the review queue you also see it in its current state. The issue here is, if someone just happens to come across a post and vote to close it, should that earn credit towards "completing reviews from the review queue" ? I say no. Nothing wrong with VTC from organically coming across a post that deserves it, but it doesn't count as reviewing. Because it's different from reviewing.

Comment: I believe this is a matter of semantics and the operative portion of your phrase is *"... from the review queue"*. The wording from the moderation badges' descriptions is closer to *"Completed at least nnn review tasks."* with a hyperlink on the word **review** that I suppose is intended to indicate that these are *Review Queue tasks*, not just any review task. Saying that a forum-level VTC or VTR is not an act of reviewing the question is just wrong to my mind. Perhaps the badges descriptions could be altered to be more specific. I know I had to look up this question to find this out.

Answer (score 4):

You write

> I'm not too concerned about the badge, cleaning the JavaScript tag is just what I do.

If one is browsing trough a list that is compiled from questions with a JavaScript tag with the intent to find bad questions and to close them, this is basically reviewing. (The compiled list is similar to a review queue).

So far, your question is understandable (to me at least).

But, it is fairly impossible for the system to detect your behavior (of going through JavaScript questions with the intent to review them) and mark is as 'reviewing'.

Hence, it is quite understandable that you do not get a review badge for your hard work.

Only thing I can say is: keep up the good work!